# Mate: Start Gui applications at startup on VPS

Tags: 17.04, ubuntu-mate, startup-applications

I have an Ubuntu 17.04 vps with Ubuntu Mate desktop installed and I connect to it through xrdp. I use transmission-gtk (GUI version) torrent client and want to start it at every boot. I tried to start it with ssh terminal but it says `no x desktop found`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer, but I think you're possibly trying to do the wrong thing.

I run Transmission on our home server via `transmission-daemon` and connect to it in a number of ways depending on where I am: browser plugins, the built-in Web UI or even the actual Transmission client.

I'm writing under the assumption that if you could connect directly, that would be better.... But you could still remote in over `xrdp` and run a local client that connected to the local daemon instance.

Otherwise you just need to square away the networking. I'm not sure I'd trust open access to a Transmission on the internet so if I were you, I'd limit the daemon to `127.0.0.1` and use SSH's port tunnelling to get access:to handle the networking side of things. I don't think I'd trust open access to Transmission on the internet. I'd use `ufw` to limit the connecting port (if you have a static IP) or do port tunnelling with SSH.

```
ssh -L 9091:localhost:9091 user@your_server.com
```

Then just browse to http://localhost:9091 (or hook up your client to that).

Comment: Thnx for the answer but security is not a problem , my xrdp server is behind a vpn server so it only accept incoming connection from ip of my vpn server , my problem is i couldnt find startup application on mate desktop (i used it for cinnamon desktop) also the startup applications wont start unless i connect to desktop while using cinnamon , unfortunately as i switched my vps provider , cinnamon desktop is having some prolems so i am new to mate desktop

Comment: I think you missed the forest for the trees. I'm suggesting you use a the command-line server version of Transmission (transmission-daemon) and connect to that directly. If this is all behind a VPN too, that's fine then. Ignore my ssh port tunnelling and you can just connect to it directly.

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer but transmission is one of the application i have other custom installed applications which should run when i login into my remote desktop , to make my question simpler , i couldnt find "Startup Application" in Mate desktop , like in cinnamon if you go to applications >> system >> startup application, there you can add applications that should start at login , as gui doesnt start with boot so adding command to rc.local or systemd script wont work

Comment: as for my answer i got it for this post https://askubuntu.com/q/507496/711546

Comment: @Solaris: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster thank you for visiting my question tho i solved my problem through multiple tries of different approach , so i didnt want to make any new question , also i cant find delete button in android app so it just stays here