# Why is my upstart process constantly respawning?

Tags: upstart

Here is my current configuration file for the service:

```
description "My App"
author "Me"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn
respawn limit 99 5
chdir /home/ubuntu/myapp/

script
    exec /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/myapp/bin/gunicorn -c /home/ubuntu/myapp/gunicorn.conf myapp.wsgi
end script
```

There is nothing wrong with the app itself, it runs fine. I can actually use it, despite it restarting constantly (several times a second). I only became aware of the problem when the log files exploded.

Previously, I did have the following clause:

```
pre-stop script
    kill -15 `cat /tmp/gunicorn.pid`
end script
```

Which I am aware [could have been causing the problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62434/why-does-upstart-keep-respawning-my-process), but I've removed it and still have the problem.

Even removing both respawn lines and doing `reload-configuration` still hasn't stopped it. What on earth is going on?

Comment: So what did those log files say?

Comment: @JdeBP Just a launch message, over and over again.